# How do I tell Apache which PHP to use?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, pdo

I am running **Apache2** on a **Mac OS X (10.5)**. I just compiled **PHP 5.2.8** and finally got `pdo-mysql` working (or so I think).

This terminal command:

```
php --version
```

is showing **5.2.8** and I have the right modules installed.

But, when I do a `phpinfo()`, **Apache** dumps out **PHP 5.2.6** (my earlier version, without `pdo_mysql`).

How do I tell Apache which PHP to load? The `httpd.conf` has the line:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But, I don't know what or where that is.

Is that what I have to change?

Comment: When you compiled php did you use make install? If you did find the path that it installed your module to and change your apache config to point to it. Mac has it's own version of apache and php5 already installed which is why you are seeing a different version.

Comment: See [OSX Apache using wrong version of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613313/osx-apache-using-wrong-version-of-php)

Comment: Homebrew users, see @Mick comment

Comment: Did you solve your problem? ALL the answers are just mad thing

Comment: None of these responses answer the question. This is bizarre...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think all these answers aren't really answering the question. The root level can be determined by running the command `httpd -V`. This will show you what options the Apache daemon was built with at compile time. This is what controls where `httpd` determines where to look for it's config. files and .so modules by default.

For example:

```
% httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 17 2010 11:58:24
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.12, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.12, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

The key line in that output is the `HTTPD_ROOT`. That defines where Apache's `ROOT` directory is to start, `/etc/httpd` in my case, when looking for config. files and modules.

**NOTE:** This `ROOT` is not the same thing as `DocumentRoot`. This `ROOT` is specific to how the `httpd` daemon was compiled, the `DocumentRoot` is for specifying where the `httpd` daemon should start looking for actual web content (.html files and such).

For my `httpd.conf` file I have the following Load lines:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
```

Given this the full path to your modules would be, for example:

```
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
```

This is from a **CentOS 5.x** system but the technique is still apt.

BTW, it can get a little confusing because in **CentOS'** case the files are organized physically here:

```
% ls /usr/lib/httpd/modules/
libphp5.so            mod_authnz_ldap.so      mod_dav_fs.so      mod_headers.so       mod_perl.so            mod_speling.so
```

...and then accessible to the Apache daemon, `httpd`, through this path:

```
% ls -l /etc/httpd/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 26  2011 conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 26  2011 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18 Feb 24  2009 htpasswd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Apr 26  2011 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Apr 26  2011 modules -> ../../usr/lib/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Apr 26  2011 run -> ../../var/run
```

The `modules` link connects `/etc/httpd` --> `/usr/lib/httpd/modules`.

Comment: ***slm*** as i stated in the previous post, the ServerRoot is defined in the ServerRoot directive and has nothing whatsoever to do with HTTPD_ROOT which is displayed via "httpd -V." Please consult Apache's web pages referenced in my previous post, or if you'd like change the ServerRoot directive in your **httpd.conf** file and see for yourself.

Comment: ServerRoot is a way to overrride HTTPD_ROOT. HTTPD_ROOT is set at compile time via the --prefix configure switch. Your post was distinguishing the different b/w ServerRoot and DocumentRoot. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serverroot. Good to see you registered a name with your SF account!

Comment: Does this really answer the question: "How do I tell Apache which PHP to use?" ?

Comment: Trix the OP accepted it so yes.

Comment: @slm This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can find files on your system with the `locate` command:

```
# locate libphp5.so
```

It will print the full paths of all files with that name. I have one at `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

Comment: So what? is this an answer to the question? Or a way to find a file?

Comment: @Trix, the asker said, "I don't know what or where that is." I've shown how to find where that is. I assumed that once the asker saw all the other locations of the named file in question, it would be apparent how to change the setting to use a different one.

Answer (score 4):

The parent directory of modules loaded in httpd.conf (such as: `libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`) is defined by the `ServerRoot` directive which by default is typically set to `/usr`. I wouldn't recommend changing this but it may be useful for someone to know just where exactly that path is defined.

Apache's website says the following about **ServerRoot**:

> Relative paths in other configuration directives (such as Include or
>   LoadModule, for example) are taken as relative to this directory.

additionally the default httpd.conf file comments read:

ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's configuration, error, and log files are kept.

Comment: The OP is not after a definition to ServerRoot. Instead (s)he has asked the question "How do I tell Apache which PHP to use?". If you really want to answer it, so answer it

Answer (score 3):

Apache should be looking for modules in "/usr/libexec/httpd/". In there you'll find either a file or symlink called "libphp5.so". If it's a symlink, you'll need to relink to the new 5.2.8 libphp5.so, otherwise just copy the 5.2.8 libphp5.so to "/usr/libexec/httpd/" and restart apache with "sudo apachectl restart".

Answer (score 0):

I had a Apache and PHP installed on one of the server. This was installed by the previous sys admin. Both the Apache and PHP was complied from the source. In addition to this there was a default PHP installed. So to know which PHP is used by the Apache. I run the below command

```
   <Install Dir of PHP>/bin/php -i | grep apxs
```

This gave me the path to apache apxs

```
  APACHE_HOME/bin/apxs
```

This gave me info on which Apache is being used by this php. The default php gave error when i typed

```
#php -i | grep apxs 

 Failed loading opcache.so:  opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No    such file or directory PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     '<PHP_HOME>/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so' - <PHP_HOME>/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLongGEZero in Unknown on line 0
```

So in this way i was able to figure out the php used by Apache.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer twice. Instead, link to the first answer.