# Apache - change php version

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have installed a new vesion of php on ubuntu.

But apache uses old version.

How to change version from 5.3 to 5.6 ?

http://joxi.net/1A5zRK5hKexKyr

I googled the question but nothing has helped

About question [How do I tell Apache which PHP to use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use)
That question is like "where I can find libphp5.so". But I know where it is and apache loads that module but verion is still 5.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Apache which PHP to use?](http://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use)

Comment: That question is like "where I can find libphp5.so". But I know where it is and apache loads that module but verion is still 5.3.

Comment: Does it load that module *instead* of the old one? Or attempt to load them both?

Comment: Can you post your apache config file?

Comment: apache config file: http://joxi.ru/vAW3VzXukbz3gA

Comment: If I try to add LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so and restart apache, it just said that module has already loaded, skipping

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `httpd.conf` to load the PHP module. The path on the right hand side of the `LoadModule` statement must point to the path of the PHP module on your system.

For example:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Afterwards, you will need to restart Apache for the new module to take effect.

Comment: there is only one libphp5.so and it is already loads  http://joxi.net/12MDVzWI4DWdJm

Comment: Try removing that .so file and reinstalling php?

Comment: Did you already restart the service?