# RHEL PHP 7.3.5 with mysqlnd and apache

Tags: mysql, redhat, php7, php.ini, extension

I'll start by stating I'm not a server admin by trade, so I've been struggling with this task.

PHP 7.3.5 was already installed on RHEL7 running Apache. I have installed MySQL successfully and now I am tasked with connecting to the MySQL DB from PHP. I have done this before on hosted services like Bluehost, but they make it easy.

I am trying to install/enable the mysqlnd/mysqli modules to absolutely no avail. phpinfo() still does not show that it's enabled. I have tried to install packages and this is what I see when I locate:

[image]

How do I enable this module so it becomes active in PHP?

Updated with command from one of the answers below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that you have everything yum installed?
Are you sure its MySQL and not MariaDB which looks like MySQL?

You can check with

```
yum list installed | grep 'sql\|mariadb'
```

You can also ask PHP directly for modules with

```
php -m | grep sql
```

and then use

```
yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server php-mysqlnd
```

or

```
yum install mariadb mariadb-devel mariadb-server php-mysqlnd
```

That should be enough to get PHP making connections to the database, although you might need some additional packages based on your project.

Oh and a silly question, did you check sql is running?

```
systemctl status mysqld
systemctl status mariadb
```

Comment: Yes, MySQL is installed and running as expected as I installed it myself. It's the connection to PHP that's is causing me pain because I did not install PHP and going by other answers it's been done incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The php directory under home seems like a sure sign that PHP was manually installed somehow. See what the system shows installed via the package manager with `sudo yum list installed | grep -i php`.

On Redhat, I believe 5.4/5.6 are the default versions that come with the OS, with other versions (including 7) being made available via the Redhat Software Collections.

You can have multiple versions of PHP installed, and it appears that what has happened here is that there are multiple versions installed, and the mysqlnd/mysqli aren't being made available to the version that Apache is using.

Comment: Do you know how to point apache to a different PHP install? I've added the result of the command above to the OP

Comment: [This may be of help.](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use)